# Formalizing emotion

Tags: emotion

Do there exist systems of formalizing emotion and their patterns? In other words, something that, for example, decomposed all emotions into combinations of a few fundamental ones or theories that predict how some follow from the other or specific metrics that can be used to classify emotion, etc. I was really fascinated by the movie “inside out”, mostly because, to me, it seemed a nice way to decompose human emotion but I assume there exist more nuanced takes on this in the literature. Are there specific terms or theories I should be looking at? Ideally, I would like a book on the subject to explore a little more ...

Comment: Welcome to Psychology & Neuroscience! The question is perfectly well-phrased. :) Therefore, feel free to edit out the preamble to your question. Many people have wondered the same, which is why there is [an entire Wikipedia page dedicated to 'emotion classification'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion_classification). However, perhaps somebody on this site can provide a more high-level overview, or summary, of different formalizations and redirect you to relevant resources.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Standard Academic set of emotions, and cognitive functions](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17265/7001).  Also see [What is the most comprehensive system of describing human emotions or states of mind?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8510/7001) and [Number of core feelings?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24549/7001).

Comment: I feel [What is the most comprehensive system of describing human emotions or states of mind?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8510/21) is a likely candidate as a duplicate. Please let me know if you agree, or edit your question to clarify more specifically what you are after.

Comment: @StevenJeuris It does answer the question but I was hoping to be recommended a larger set of source material to look at like a book. Would you know anything like that?

Comment: Now that you know what to look for, don't you think you can find suitable books yourself? Ultimately, deciding which one to read is fairly opinion-based and not a good format for this site. Unless, you have a very specific requirement which can help people understand why you would like one book over another.